# Find email address that are part of a domain exclusion data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, suppressionlist, exclusion-script

I'm looking to find all email addresses in our database where the email address domain is included in one of our domain exclusion data extension.

I thought of using something like the below, but it isn't feasible given we have over 3k domains that are part of our domain exclusion data extension.

```
SELECT * FROM [mytable]
  WHERE Email_Address LIKE 'domain1'
  OR Email_Address LIKE 'domain2'
  OR Email_Address LIKE 'domain3'
```

Is this even possible in SFMC and if so, what supporting documentation exists?

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish something like this by joining the [_subscribers data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) with the domain exclusions table on the users email address domain in order to find matches between the two.

To identify a user's domain with SQL, you can use this snippet:

```
RIGHT(EmailAddress, LEN(EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', EmailAddress))
```

The rest of the query should be as simple as an inner join.

Comment: in the _subscribers dataview there is already a domain filed that can be leveraged

Comment: Yep, that should make it easier but he'll still need to find the domain on the exclusions table as well to join them (which is why I included the above snippet).